# Razor page custom post method not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post, get, razor-pages

Why this:

```
<form method="post">
  <nav>
   <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" asp-page-handler="filter" asp-route-id="1">1</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </form>
```

Does not fire OnPostFilter method inside backend?

```
public void OnGet()
    {
        ProdGoal = 15000;
        FillChart();
    }

    public void OnPostFilter(string id)
    {
        int MonthNum;
        if (int.TryParse(id, out MonthNum) && MonthNum >= 1 && MonthNum <= 12)
            FillChart(MonthNum);
        else
            FillChart();
    }
```

It always fires OnGet(). But when I would move the  tag in front of  it would work. Why is that? How should I make  fire Post method.

Comment: Where are you giving OnPostFilter?

Comment: @viveknuna What do you mean? Its the cs file behind front end for this page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because tag a always creates an HTTPRequest of Get Type and by click on the generated link, does not send information to the server by form tag. If you want to call the OnPostFilter Handler, you must create a HTTPRequest of Post Type. For creation Post HTTPRequest, you must create a submit element in Form Tag.

```
<form method="post">
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item">
                <button class="page-link" asp-page-handler="filter" asp-route-id="1">1</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</form>
```

or

```
<form method="post">
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item">
                <input type="submit" class="page-link" asp-page-handler="filter" asp-route-id="1" value="1" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the request method is get when you click `<a class="page-link" asp-page-handler="filter" asp-route-id="1">1</a>`,so you cannot go to post handler.

1.You can try to change the handler name to `OnGetFilter`:

```
public void OnGetFilter(string id)
    {
        int MonthNum;
        if (int.TryParse(id, out MonthNum) && MonthNum >= 1 && MonthNum <= 12)
            FillChart(MonthNum);
        else
            FillChart();
    }
```

2.If you don't want to change the handler name,try to change your html:

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="filter" asp-route-id="1">
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item">
                <input type="submit" value="1"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok maybe I dont understand purpose of get/post. It was my understanding that every click on the page calls post method. I am still new to razor pages.

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you accept it as an answer?Thank you.

Comment: It doesn´t really answer my question but it could lead someone to a solution

Answer (score 0):

I have changed

```
<input type="submit" value="1"/>
```

for

```
<button ... />
```

Now it works but I still don´t know why input is firing OnGet()

Comment: Links create Get http requests. You need forms for Post http requests. This is the way html and all web applications work.